# Why does input DC supply gets short circuited when operational amplifier is connected at the output of LLC resonant converter?

Tags: operational-amplifier, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, feedback, resonant-converter

Following is the block diagram of LLC resonant converter, more clear circuit can be found [here](https://viewer.diagrams.net/?tags=%7B%7D&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=complete_circuit.drawio#R7V1bc5s4FP41eYwHiZt5TJyk2520k93Mtt2nDDGyTYuRCzix99evZJABIYywuZi6nVEDQhfQ%2Bc4n6ehIvlIny82HwF4tPmEHeVdQcTZX6t0VhKoyNskfGrONY%2BA%2BZh64ThwH0ohn9z%2BURCpJ7Np1UJhLGGHsRe4qHznFvo%2BmUS7ODgL8niRLipthL1%2Fryp6jQsTz1PaKsV9dJ1okn6GqVvrgD%2BTOF0nVqqokVS1tljqJCBe2g98zUer9lToJMI7iq%2BVmgjzafKxh4nwPJU%2F3bxYgP5LJMP%2F4J7odO9%2B8mf%2BXuvHtxeRWuzbHyctFW%2FbJyCEtkNz62Cd%2FbgO89h1Ey1HIHQ6iBZ5j3%2FYeMV6RSEAiv6Mo2ibys9cRJlGLaOklT9HGjb4l2en1v%2FR6pCd3d5vMo7tt5uYJBe4SRShI4mbYj5JK4C6N79xQKaevSmIeXM9jZfgMU4C%2BRhgF%2BAeaYA%2FTAh00s9ceabvbuA3oh5e2bRIV4nUwRQcaFOwlS5QCYfLywZbkC5BnR%2B5bvnw7Aed8n26f9Qm7pGaoME1iIEr0SDWUfBGRHcxRlORKQUAax95mkq1ogrC8HmDpwnqS4shFXCK7y3xjGrXDXQ0MJq3xZnvrpH0KmHxDQeQSrXy0X5H3hEM3crFPHr3iKMJLKlmmXFTqjh0u9mi1PXdOk06JKCmObmcEHgwCV4Sjdv%2FycGXV3SR5IwrzBD2MBkBc64q%2B4XIzp%2Fw3Qh7hoIDmHC3dcEq%2B3fYRXoejJfYxvX15tSPyFlv6km5AEsef4VOV2uOQ1o42h5FYRBjLYOQlCBkfvaf0xcCzyBAXUJRyUGbkX1%2B8ptkpxYBfnmJgOxQDxKpfRTFNsQCsZoEde6Hg%2Fg1REsurahPMUM0A5fo%2BtVf21I1wEKaXL5DTcyLapvQcjs9Nz1WBAI0d9l%2FJxTxWgjiC6lhOtMbPNWYPrsOdOt2QBGC82qQPWSkPa8%2B7viXDRaJLrIaAPfzo75o1KD5hMeTj4voL0Zn35JCXZ6f3hRuhZyJk%2BvSdICGPnQakq3L9MFCL0gVAIF6otSVebdj66frOerpTT3b1ojYjK13jZGXBoqwUgazGLUlKH7akhEzakF4ZvKxMgV6JZMV3ho0JyyhlTWmStEQkWeDePGvaSyoF%2FzVcZdPuufLOJVN5UvbftOuauRV0WuD3AsX2TKeWeXZ0ag5bSVM6jQLbD2c4WKJYS1sa75hW9XjHEo13YFsSHA9bgl0PWIkgjhyxtiZBa9gSDFDohjsBsqtW5cePSUXyg53KD0hYjjINnO91mrIXkOYLtt%2ByN5mS6G1a1O5um73jCyuzHlQZIa4aNmBCJZ7tH0hXYoUQDaROtEwYnElL5aew8TcVLBOFgsyqglqyooK8FbWQHur10vOmGtCJlVZiWlGubBX4PdVq1gkOy5q9Ng4Ls%2FuOTW1ANOloW5QpT44UAPNcaRnHkKU86VWSmdobiApm1rbJrDEQScxgWgRRFkCgZ%2FRonaFHLxtDDw49ErOn5tHT6pCvZRRWDtx0SbSanaG194FbY2iVmCm2htacz0RtrDYIsAEChzf8Ffiy7UVNpc9OEnRIT2dEO3wnqfIGiKHQDjzJvtEoepSLQQ9PGcNFD%2BwTPU1YwxrEz7gz%2FAClzDOjLoCAwnvjdY0giTX%2FrvjnkhF0NAX1j6A%2BjIbnykFWdwiC6i%2FDQb3aKs%2BMg3pE0IA5yCoA5py3ODTKXm2vu8h4K5ungVsayKc5ryqdguSsFp2HBBJYMgzrBiVw4F5bHXuM6GWjkCqPkfZ81EFBXq2oeefL3ad291qVzaykky6WNOZcbA3ehbJk4FDbyYL3u2YVlb6ZZtTNoJyYQee3ZFZl0PQOPDmYt8lA%2Brq6G7K66K5O7YVqQrqzofLAfVp77t%2B03vs3XetUteWWJvUBabamiEXetGarQBnBsW4CLf6fPe5I0RmvnLLtRLg37%2FFB1VXZbSDHsUKtbdgenrvTl7kdoXDkrG3vxfU910cv7pTk8yhdfbaXuwMm7Cs4eSVhSoJDAiJhRsKchAUJLgnfSfhBAmnfyZIEnwRMwoqEnyQEJJAhy4R%2BbUh96v05xb8A6rv7pCXYKt9JXMQPu%2Fau9FnjkIiMrLa4SOtorN30lFp63ROUzqjPkdiSnrzama0RBqw7mocKf26B2cFImDXKhR09wcOzpaMooMKPj2CRk7rdo66pw%2BSkJsx850hKsj6LsaL2ZfbTehxVN4eaA5gxf03Q9NOTgXE9qxFUYE0zU5mJTToDZ5dqqXOVWPv%2F3bke3bkC%2Few6V6M%2FmiwlSdAcS6qts6RgVtigVeNsKROYvMucWUFohQxWF3bzBs7qMKTO6vgynRYP3NC%2FlB%2FCkcY8Pf8DbmQSnnJ%2BB6GtSGSUYYhOQJ9l5CSqwNo8JS9dx6HVCE8FyXNHAywKrDG%2FAKNLsajamgVXtMScBVkJZFhEuLL945F4%2FSUDgbgo0cldR1apiKq8v6%2BosgjZ07Tt%2BpAilRwO1vQ7UC2tX6fUyWUXpsGQP1akfw0WLaLxBP%2Fxs4DgFVmGhwcxUn6M3XlInR8tNcHj3K5qKDjgqVsQiHYMciB4DC5baDqTCDsGQetZaKyyQ0KbXLjQ%2BK2Z%2FQtNtEmOExpp%2FxvzsuU2BpyyGbBnuUEJZZtdttAA1EG%2BX9P71jaJU37%2FfrxwqWn8aKR3qYk28vFSAxcuNV0%2FszGkITKg81KDv6WWk5qm9jz9MyT2CLD1hWmAw%2FDVDkpaT7ivDQgasi0HR83KDxqgYI1B5FOktbbGYEhMrmFmIn2hWqFpecGJPFM71QpTNG4YqFYY3FBaFXQUIq1oz9XOlOjfwUi%2FdK0wuF9R6t1UaHa8Yrp3JpE4Syo9rnHvbSRzjNCBpdCpZ4fhzvE2XQ099JM53C%2FrxE3VzElWsi4kJedCduN2ZEqM%2F56%2Bfiragj8gHwV2hOVMVbUO429BLVULjjj3FOHx%2FHpRMY%2F4VQZym%2F7kXrwynP50oXr%2FPw%3D%3D).

[image: complete circuit]

This is an LLC resonant converter which produces 250V across RL with 50V at input without any issue. But when operational amplifier [LF353](https://www.st.com/en/amplifiers-and-comparators/lf353.html) is connected across the output through voltage divider (R1 and R2 as shown in diagram) the display of the input power supply **PSU2** turns to zero Volts and zero Amps. This is very strange behavior of the circuit. While the same operational amplifier when given input from **PSU2** works perfectly as a unity gain buffer. The circuit configuration for this case is shown below:

[image]

**Note 1:** Power supplies used in the circuit are:

1. PSU1A and PSU1B are the two channels of TTi EX354RT
2. PSU2 is one of two channels of TTi EX752M

The link to power supplies datasheet is [here](https://resources.aimtti.com/datasheets/AIM-EL-R+EX-R_series_DC_power_supplies_data_sheet-Iss1.pdf).

**Note 2:** Output of the converter is not grounded.

The purpose of this setup is to design a feedback loop to regulate the output voltage of the converter.

Comment: "the input power supply designated as PSU2 gets short circuited! This is extremely strange behavior of the circuit. While the same operational amplifier when given input from PSU2 works perfectly" ????

Comment: Opamp is used as unity gain buffer, so we expect it to produce the same voltage at its output as applied on its input. PSU1A and PSUB are the positive and negative power supplies. For opamp input voltage we have two cases, 1) Input voltage from PSU2 (a separate power supply). 2) Input voltage from voltage divider when DC input to resonant converter is from PSU2. In case 1 opamp works perfectly (means its gives same output as its input voltage), but in case 2 when PSU2 is turned on to power the converter its display turn off and maximum current LED turns on depicting short circuit condition.

Comment: What values do R1 and R2 have?

Comment: R1 = 333kOhms, R2 = 2.2kOhms